# php dl() for loading extensions is removed from some SAPIs

Tags: php, php-extension

I'm reading on the `dl()` function (which lets you load extensions manually), and the [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php) says

> WARNING: This function has been removed from some SAPI's in PHP 5.3.

Does anyone know what this means. **SAPI** seems to mean **Server API**, but I'm not sure what exactly this means.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That very page says

> The only SAPI's that allow dl() are: CLI, CGI and Embed. Use the Extension Loading Directives instead.

You can determine what sapi you are using with `php_sapi_name()`.  At least for me, running it on the command line returns "cli."